# building ffmpeg library for android on linux

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg libaray on linux for my android application. 
The link which I am following is https://www.assetbank.co.uk/support/documentation/install/ffmpeg/ 
I have successfully completed all the steps except the last one 
i.e " Run "/sbin/ldconfig" as root. "

It is showing the following error in the linux terminal:
anirudh@anirudh-System-Product-Name:/sbin$ ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied

Please comment if anyone can suggest something regarding this issue.

Comment: You're not running the required command as root, are you ? Seems you are using your normal user account (anirudh).

Comment: Thanks for your comment SirDarius, I am running the /sbin/ldconfig as root, And I have two user account anirudh and guest user. So anirudh here is an administrator... But still the command is showing permission denied error!!!.....   Please suggest any solution

Comment: I'm repeating myself here, but please run the command as root and show us the corresponding output... your username should not appear in the prompt.